# Cannot login using Python Requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to do some web scraping using python with Requests module in a session, but I always failed to login, and [here](https://boymeetsshe.stores.jp/login) is the site. I know there are a lot of similar questions but I have really tried most of the solutions. So I guess I have to post a new one. This is my code so far. This site contains a csrf-token in the requests header and I have included it already.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
from lxml import etree

requests_url = 'https://boymeetsshe.stores.jp/login'   

session = requests.Session()         #Session

page = session.get(requests_url).text    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")    
soup_token = soup.find_all(attrs={"name": 'csrf-token'})         #This is for the token
token = soup_token[0]['content']    


login = {
            "email": "MYEMAIL",
            "password": "MYPASSWORD"
        }

header = {
            'Referer': 'https://boymeetsshe.stores.jp/login?redirect_uri=/',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
            'authority': 'boymeetsshe.stores.jp',
            'method': 'POST',
            'x-csrf-token':token
         }

session.post(requests_url, data = login, headers = header)
page1 = session.get('https://boymeetsshe.stores.jp/mypage/settings',headers = header)
print(page1.text)
```

I am not sure if I made a stupid mistake or not, but I really tried a lot of solutions already and still can't figure out my problems. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when you try this code?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for the comment.There is no error but it shows the main site instead of my page, which indicates failling to login.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a good idea to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for login, read the documentation and use it, but I try to say here how to use it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import os
import time

chromedriver = "driver/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

username_login = 'MYEMAIL'
password_login = 'MYPASSWORD'


def login(driver , username_login ,password_login):

    login_link = 'https://boymeetsshe.stores.jp/login'
    driver.get(login_link)
    time.sleep(5)

    username_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('that input element XPath or css selector')
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('that input element xpath or css selector')

    username_input.send_keys(username_login)
    password_input.send_keys(password_login)

    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('that login button element xpath or css selector')
    login_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But as stated in the description, my major purpose is to do some web scraping including downloading images, extracting texts and so on. Selenium can help me login into the website, but it only interacts with the browser in stead of allowing me to extract the information without inetraction with the browser. But thank you very much for the answer.